# PHPSESSID only showing/working when served through HTTPS, despite session.cookie_secure being 0

Tags: php

I'm having a issue with PHP (7) and SESSIONS. I've been doing all the work on localhost, and just moved my code onto a site which i generated a self signed certificate on, working as intended.

I added session.cookie_secure = 1; after my session_start(); to all pages. 
Now of course the sessions wouldn't work over insecure HTTP. 
However despite changing the value to 0 also in the php.ini configuration it's still not working.

This is the result of var_dump($_SESSION):

https://imgur.com/a/wavv5

The code:

ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', 1);

ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);

ini_set('session.cookie_secure', 0);

session_start();

Any suggestions? All i can think of is that PHP somehow cached the cookie_secure to 1?

Answer (score 0):

this would help :

```
$secure = false;
$httponly = true;
$cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams['lifetime'], $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly);
session_start();
```

otherwise, why would you want session to be sent over http if you already have ssl on ?

Comment: That doesn't do it either.

Because it's a self-signed certificate so every visitor will get a red lock (i added a exception in my own browser). I want the application to work over HTTP too.

Answer (score 0):

Hah, that's odd. I tested insecure HTTP on another PC, and the PHPSESSID showed without issues. I then cleared my browser history and cookies in my browser and it worked! It was obviously some caching issue in my browser, for anyone else with this problem.